# Cannot use an Xaml component from a C# WinRT Component in C++/WinRT Xaml Islands project

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, c++-winrt, xaml-islands

How to replicate (we will use Windows Terminal as example):

1. Clone the Windows Terminal repo and fetch submodules
2. Create a C# Windows Runtime Component in the solution with a `UserControl` with some random controls
3. Reference the C# WinRT Component from the project you want to host the `UserControl` in
4. Open an Xaml page in one of Windows Terminal projects (we will use `TerminalPage.xaml` from `TerminalAppLib` project as an example)
5. Add the `UserControl` to that page
6. Compile and run (you might need to include the generated Xaml compiled files of the `UserControl` to `pch.h` file for it to compile without Xaml Compiler errors)
7. You will find that the app will crash with `class not registered` exception

What I have tried:

1. Using `Class Library` instead of `WinRT Component`
2. https://a.rcad.io/csharp-in-cppwinrt
3. https://github.com/asklar/WinRTComponent/blob/master/README.md
4. Registering the class in `WindowsTerminal.manifest` file, like this (I used `.dll` instead of `.winmd` when I tried with `Class Library`):

```xml
<file name="myWinRTComponent.winmd" hashalg="SHA1" xmlns:winrt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1">
    <winrt:activatableClass name="Namespace.UserControlClass" threadingModel="both" />
</file>
```

5. Registering the class manually in `AppxManifest.xml` file

Comment: You could try to add a xmlns statement `xmlns:runtimecom="using:RuntimeComponent"` into the MainPage.xaml file.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT that's actually what I use to add the `UserControl` from the C# WinRT Component into the page that in the C++/WinRT Xaml Islands project

Comment: You could try to set your C# component’s minimum version to Windows 10 version 1703 (Build 15063) or lower: From your C# project, go to Properties, Library, and under Targeting, set the Min version to Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0; Build 15063) or lower.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT it didn't work, the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the solution
we have to register against `CLRHost.dll` instead of the Runtime Component Winmd file

So if the app is ***packaged*** we have to add that inside the `Extensions` tag (which is inside the `Package` tag not the one that inside the `Application` tag) of `Package.appxmanifest` (keeping in mind that `Namespace` is the namespace of the control **and** the Runtime Component name/assembly name & `UserControlClass` is the name of the `UserControl` class)

```xml
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>CLRHost.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Namespace.Namespace_XamlTypeInfo.XamlMetaDataProvider" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Namespace.UserControlClass" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

And we have to add this to `Application.manifest` inside the `assembly` tag if the app is ***unpackaged*** (keeping in mind that `Application` is the name of the application & `Namespace` is the namespace of the control **and** the Runtime Component name/assembly name & `UserControlClass` is the name of the `UserControl` class)

```xml
<file name="CLRHost.dll" xmlns:winrt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1">
    <winrt:activatableClass name="Namespace.Namespace_XamlTypeInfo.XamlMetaDataProvider" threadingModel="both"/>
    <winrt:activatableClass name="Namespace.UserControlClass" threadingModel="both"/>
</file>
```